# How to add a chargePoint using curl in php to steVe ocpp server?

Tags: php, curl

I want to add a chargePoint using curl with php on steVe ocpp server and i'm wondering if someone knows how to do that.

I didn't find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of some of the Web UIs is offered as REST APIs as well.

https://github.com/steve-community/steve/wiki/Configuration#rest-apis

Other REST-Endpoints are not defined by default

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35269294)